plugs not working, breaker not tripped
My paranoid schizophrenic nephew disabled my mom's garage plugs to keep garage door openers from working.  The breaker was not tripped and when I removed panel cover could tell it had never been done before as well as wiring was all still correct.  The first plug in the circuit was fine as well as wires going to it when I went into the attic, all following wires looked intact as well as far as I could see.
My question is could he have unwired another plug in the circuit that would essentially leave the circuit open where all plugs in the circuit will not work?
I have flipped the breaker not knowing what he has done, I would like to figure this out without the expense of an electrician.  So we go back to my question above.  Thank you.

Is the first plug in the circuit GFCI, and have you tried resetting it? Garages normally have GFCI circuits. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51941/do-all-garage-receptacles-have-to-be-gfci-protected-and-18-inches-off-the-groun

None of the plugs are GFCI.  The first plugs is a ceiling plug for garage door opener, splits off after that for a wall mount plug and the other garage door opener, splits off that to another wall mount plug.

What happens when you run an extension cord from a known good plug to the garage door opener?

Have you examined all the exposed wiring? A nipped hot after the working outlet would explain the dead outlets downstream.

It's possible for a GFCI to be tucked away.  I found one in a bathroom closet.

Did you test the outlets with a light or something else?  I would have disabled the opener itself.


My question is could he have unwired another plug in the circuit that would essentially leave the circuit open where all plugs in the circuit will not work?

Each receptacle normally feeds the next receptacle, so wherever they are disconnected, the ones following don't work. The ones before the disconnected one will work, if that's the only factor.
If the receptacle in question is a GFCI receptacle and the following receptacles are wired from its LOAD terminals, they won't work if it has tripped or the Test button has been pushed (which trips it) until it is Reset. If there is an actual ground fault (more common) or it has failed (common, but less common than actual faults) it may not reset.
Since GFCI protection is typically required for garages, there may be a GFCI in the circuit. That can be a breaker, a receptacle, or a "deadfront" GFCI (basically like a receptacle but with only the test and reset buttons, no actual holes for a plug to plug in to.)
One reason a GFCI might trip would be if someone opened up a box on the circuit fed from its LOAD terminals and attempted to change the wiring with the power on.
If there is power at the breaker, but no power at the first receptacle, and there is no GFCI, either you have incorrectly assessed the panel wiring as good (a person attempting to disable a circuit might well take care to conceal the tampering from casual inspection) or the wiring from the panel to the device has been compromised somewhere in between. Or you may have missed a GFCI as the actual first device on the circuit. In older work it was not uncommon for the GFCI protecting the garage to be located in the basement, a bathroom, or some other "odd" location. Newer code has made those practices less common (and GFCIs are not as relatively expensive as they were, then.)
